# Listing all figures (tables, algorithm) once again at the end of the document

Tags: algorithm, list, latex, figure

I have been writhing a rather large document with LaTeX.
Now I would like to list all the figures / tables / algorithms once again at the end of the file so that I can check if they all look the same.

For example, if every algorithm has the same notation.

How can I do this?

I know about `\listofalgorithms` and  `\listoffigures` but they only list the names of the algorithms or figures and the pages where they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hendri Adriaens' extract package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract/) has roughly the functionality you are after: you can extract named environments, including figures and tables to a supplementary Latex file, which you can then run to get the document containing the extracted content.  The extracted content could then be tacked to the end of the original document using pdfpages.

Comment: I only needed the figures and algorithm to check them, so this was a perfect solution.

Note that when I extracted all ~20 Figures without any other text in the document, latex did not compiled.
The latex error was ! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.
After I have manually inserted some text it worked.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a package designed to do excatly what you ask. I have not used it myself, though. See http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/figcaps.pdf.

Comment: This package only works on article class documents.
So not quite perfect.

Comment: Now: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/figcaps.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a number of hackeries you can employ but the easiest way is probably to play with float placement. If you redefine the figure environment and basically ignore the placement parameters (and force it to [p]) then you have everything at the end and you can check for consistency.

There is no standard way to reprint all pictures at the end though.

Comment: Is there any way to globally define this?
I tried \renewenvironment{figure} but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to temporary put all floats at the end, I recommend using the [endfloat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/) package. It puts all your floats on single pages at the end of the document.